# Equivalent to AWS Hostname in Azure?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, azure-virtual-machine

in AWS these 2 commands provide value for my configuration

```
 export FQDN=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname`
export PRIVATE_FQDN=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname`
```

now if I want similar setup for linux VM in Azure how can I retrieve it using Metadata service ??

One command I know is this

curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01"

But this command only return ip and machine specific data and not host names in Azure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01"` to retrieve all metadata for an instance.

As you could see, Azure does not provide host name.

So, the answer is impossible.

Not: By defualt, VM's host name equals VM's name.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: FQDN for VM is vm's name + '.' + vm's location  + '.cloudapp.azure.com' .

Comment: No, FQDN is `dns name`+ '.vm's location' +`cloudapp.azure.com`. dns name could different with vm's name. The meta api could not get FQDN, but you could get VM's public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly right, the command you have returns network information because you have speficied /network after /instance. If you use the command below you should get all the instance metadata

> curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01"

You can find further details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service

Comment: I am sorry I gave the wrong command. Just updated it . Point is I want hostname information by this or any other command how is that possible.

Answer (score 1):

That command should return a 'name' value which is the VM name and should also be the hostname. You can also look in /etc/hostname

More details here is you need further reading.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-viewing-and-modifying-hostnames

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done as of 2023. Metadata API only returns public IP information. Some people share tricks how to figure out DNS alias from VM name, but this is actually incorrect - if you create VMs through API then they are created without any DNS alias. You can also change DNS alias to `ANYTHING.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com` where `eastus` is the location/region the VM is running in.

You can fetch this externally tho, not from the VM (that would be a huge security hole), but from an external system which knows the VM UUID and can ask the Azure DNS API.